# XSL:when - Apply multiple attributes

Tags: css, xml, class, xslt

I'm trying to apply more than one class to an attribute via test.

This is probably really simple, but I can't figure out how to do it. I've tried separating the classes in a single line and also stacking them like so:

```
<xsl:when test="@name = 'Example' and @status = 'Example2'">
     <xsl:attribute name="class">style1</xsl:attribute>
     <xsl:attribute name="class">style2</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:when>
```

When I try it this way it applies the second class, but not the first. When I put two classes into the same line it doesn't work at all.

Ideas would be much appreciated!

Comment: You have to decide for one or the other, because an element can only have attributes with unique names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML "class" attribute should contain a list of all classes, separated by spaces:

```
<xsl:when test="@name = 'Example' and @status = 'Example2'">
    <xsl:attribute name="class">style1 style2</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:when>
```

If you use multiple `<xsl:attribute>`s with the same name, the XSLT processor will only use the last one.

Comment: Ah, this was the way I tried it initially. This does kind of work, but it didn't work with mine when I had an :after in the CSS.

Comment: Turns out I just ordered my CSS badly. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

An element cannot have two attributes with the same name. From the [XML specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-starttags):

> An attribute name MUST NOT appear more than once in the same start-tag or empty-element tag.